# Is there a PHP function to convert a query string to an array?

Tags: php

I'm basically looking for the opposite of `http_build_query()`.

I have the following as a string:

```
foo=bar&bar[var]=foo
```

And I want the following (to pass into `http_build_query`):

```
array(
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'bar' => array(
         'var' => 'foo',
    )
)
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You want [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). Pass it an array as the 2nd parameter and it will extract variables from the query string you give it into the array:

```
<?php
$str = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";

parse_str($str, $output);

print_r($output);

/*
Array
(
    [first] => value
    [arr] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo bar
            [1] => baz
        )

)
*/
```

Notice this is the very first related function listed on the [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) page.

Comment: Quick note: providing the second parameter (in this example, `$output`) is mandatory as of PHP 7.2.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it will work . [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) 2nd parameter mandatory as of PHP 7.2+

```php
parse_str(urldecode($builded_content), $output)

print_r($output)
```