# Slim framework get value of var_export

Tags: php

Hello so I have this few lines of slim framework code and I wanted to get values of var_export. This is the code:

```
$request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
var_export($request->getBody());
```

The output of this is:

```
'txt_title=hello&txt_author=hi';
```

And by using `parse_str()`:

```
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $values = var_export($request->getBody());
    parse_str($values, $output);
    echo $output['txt_title'];
```

I am now getting undefinex index: txt_title.

What could be the possible remedy for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a PHP function to convert a query string to an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951454/is-there-a-php-function-to-convert-a-query-string-to-an-array)

Comment: @D4V1D Now I am getting the error Undefined index: txt_title

Comment: Can you edit the question with what you've done so far?

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($output);`. What's the output?

Comment: @D4V1D I got array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Right. Drop the `var_export()` and just do `parse_str($request->getBody(), $output);`.

Comment: @D4V1D Wow. That was easy. Can you post your answer so I can vote as best :)

Comment: @D4V1D Yes done, just waited for some minutes so I can accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the correct code is:

```
$request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
$values = $request->getBody(); // note the absence of var_export() function
parse_str($values, $output); // use parse_str()
echo $output['txt_title'];
```

And that was it.

Please note that:

- [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) is the — exact? — opposite of [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)
- [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) in different from [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). The former *exports* the variable so it's readable by PHP. The latter *dumps* it so you can have all its property/method/length/whatever.