# Store HTML array values into javascript array to be sent via AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a form, in which I am able to clone a table row. Each form element is is named as an array with [] after the name. This is no big deal if I am sending the form directly to a PHP script. I do not wish to refresh so I need to store the values in a javascript array then send that array to my php script etc. I am having a difficult time creating a NEW javascript variable that is an array of all the values.

One this is complete I'm sure requesting it in PHP is pretty straight forward.

Here is an example of my HTML form.

```
<form  class="form8" name="formfine">
  <table  class="tablesorter2" cellspacing="0" id="adddate"> 
    <tbody> 
      <tr> 
        <td>Expense:</td>
        <td>
          <select id="fineexpense" name='fineexpense[]'>
            <option value='Mortage/Rent'>Mortage/Rent</option>
            <option value='Auto'>Auto</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Here is my current AJAX function

```
function ajax_finesave(){

var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "PHP/FFfinesave.php";
var fineexpense = document.formfine.elements['fineexpense[]'];
```

any help on this would be great, also the correct way to request an ajax sent variable would be helpful.Thank you

Comment: The `[]` is not really an "array notation". It is just the behavior php shows when processing a request argument with a key (name) with that pattern. So you have to do the same in javascript: you create a selector that returns all matching elements and iterate over the resulting set. Then you pick the values in each iteration and put them into a javascript array.

Comment: You got a lot of row with same name and id??

Comment: it all depends, could be just one or 10, depends on user interaction.

Comment: @AndrewBrown it doesn't really matter what tech is involved your form fields will require unique names, for js, life will be easier if they have unique ids too, though there's no reason the id and name on an individual field can't be the same

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the structure of how to accomplish what i want all together. All I'm wanting to do is make sure dynamically created rows in my form field get captured by a javascript variable so i can send it to PHP script via AJAX... Thanks for you reply.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple way using JQuery which is to serialise the form. The function is [here](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

The usage is ...

`$('.form').serialize();`

... and the resulting value is a query string that can be sent as a single variable to the server and dissected as required by your php, using a function like [`parse_str()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951454/is-there-a-php-function-to-convert-a-query-string-to-an-array)

Another thing to remember about JavaScript is it's array can't be used like a keyed hash, as you'd see in PHP. You need to use an object for keys. So, you won't be able to create an array in JavaScript that mimics a php `$_POST` array.

You could build a JSON object out of your form and post that using AJAX (JQuery's [version here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) then use php's [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to unwrap it server side. Do pay attention to the `$assoc` argument here as you need that to get an array in php.

A JQuery example follows:

```
var myJSON = {
  formField: $('.form-field').val(),
  anotherFormField: $('.another-form-field').val()
}

$.ajax({
  url: 'my-url',
  method: 'post',
  data: {
    formJSON: myJSON
  },
  success: function() {
    // success update here
  }
});
```

In the example `myJSON` is a JavaScript object with named keys which are populated with the form field values (though anything will do). This is how you'd mimic php associative arrays in JavaScript.