# How to read GET values from HTTP_REFERER with PHP

Tags: php, apache

How can I read the values of get header variables which are from `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` such as if I had `index.php?col=example&order=example2` how could I read the values of col and order from the string which is received from `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` and would this be safe?

I thought of using strpos() but that would mean I would have to make a function to find the position of `col` for example and then read the value starting from thr `=` and stop at the next `&` or null value if only one get header is set...

Comment: You would use `$_GET['col']` and `$_GET['order']`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I can't use that method because they don't exist and I can only get them from the HTTP_REFERER...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951454/is-there-a-php-function-to-convert-a-query-string-to-an-array), use [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), like this:

```
$str = 'index.php?col=example&order=example2';
$qs = parse_url($str, PHP_URL_QUERY);
if(!empty($qs)){
    parse_str($qs, $output);
    // TODO check for key existence
    echo $output['col'];  // example
    echo $output['order']; // example2
}
```

The difference is that it won't work with `index.php?`, so we get just the query string part from the url.

I suggest you do some checking to make the script more reliable.

Comment: This is a bit convoluted. Just use `parse_url($str, PHP_URL_QUERY)` instead of `explode`. If the string is empty then you know you don't have any GET parameters in the referrer. If it's not, `parse_str` like in your answer.