# How to get an array from GET URL parameters in Laravel

Tags: laravel, url, get

Hello to everyone who is seeing this! I am a Laravel beginner, using Laravel for API-s calls. I cannot find an appropriate solution how to pick up parameters from GET method that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/products/searchv2/cat=category1&cat=category2
```

Now I want to receive in my Laravel controller this array

```
$categories = ["category1", "category2"]
```

I think the solution is very easy, but due to minimal experience, I cannot find the right answer on the internet or Laravel documentation. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple HTTP GET parameters with the same identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980228/multiple-http-get-parameters-with-the-same-identifier)

Comment: Check accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951454/is-there-a-php-function-to-convert-a-query-string-to-an-array).

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3980323/8292439), you can use the `[]` syntax like you would with form fields to create an array. So in your case, the URL would be:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/products/searchv2/?cat[]=category1&cat[]=category2
```

And `$_GET['cat']` should return an array, so in theory `$request->get('cat')` would also return an array.

### Using Commas

Another way would be to make use of commas, e.g.:

```
?cat=category1,category2,category3
```

You could then use `explode`:

```php
$categories = explode($request->get('cat'));
```

Comment: explode function is working for me, thank you a lot!